# how to render grid with lines and semi-transparent color?

Tags: materials

[image]

I want to make the above grid with the following style. Semi-transparent color, with lines. How can I do that?  via materials?

[image]

Comment: Search for Freestyle or try Viewport to SVG addon (from Liero) ...

Comment: should the grid lines lay on the edges or "free" adjustable?

Comment: if it's completely flat you could use a texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to use a grid texture with alpha values between the lines and work with that information for the desired transparency effect. Still, the grid lines could potentionally show some aliasing effect, which i guess you want to avoid. So here is a procedural material setup, which should serve you as a starting point:
[image: procedural grid]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution close to Taiyo's one, use a *Brick Texture* as factor between a Transparent and a half transparent shader in order to create your grid:

[image]